# Building an PHP XML string (with addChild()) and loading it on other pages

Tags: php, xml, node.js

I created an XML string with the following code:

```
$xmlstr = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<product_list>
</product_list>
XML;
```

Then I included this php file into another php page, and work with the addChild() to insert a new node.

```
include 'xml.php';
$product = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
$newprod = $product->addChild("product");
$newprod->addChild("reference", $xml->product[$ref_prod]->reference);
...
```

But when I'm trying to add another "product" node (by going to another page), the XML string will not keep the first "product" node.

How can I keep the XML string with the added nodes during my session, and by landing to other pages? Do I have to create a kind of session variable? Or constant? Or class?
Or is there an easier way to work with XML through a batch of pages?

Comment: You need to *select* the root node before you can start adding children.

Comment: PHP only does what you tell it to do. You don't tell it to persist the variable in some data-store from one script execution to the other. So as you don't persist your changes to the XML somewhere (a file on disk for example), those are lost. Please note that this a general principle that has nothing to do with XML. Same would be for a string containing text that you change. Or a number that you count up.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to a new page, the whole process starts all over again. If you want to manipulate
the same xml, you will have to pass it (as a string or as an object) from one page to the other somehow.

The easiets here is most probably storing it in a session variable

Your include could look like s
this:

```
// make the sessionaccessible
session_start();

// create xml if it does not exist
if(!$_SESSION['mysimplexml'])
{
   // create the string 
   $xmlstr = <<<XML
             <?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
             <product_list>
             </product_list>
             XML;   

   // parse it into the simplexml object
   $product = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

   // store in the session variable
   $_SESSION['mysimplexml'] = $product;
}
```

In all the pages you use this includeyou would do

```
// get the xml from session
$product = $_SESSION['mysimplexml'];

// manipulate xml code code here

// store back into session
$_SESSION['mysimplexml'] = $product;
```